# How to avoid "Video not found or access denied" error for anonymous users in a Drupal video sharing site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a web application in Drupal 6 that shows video content to users. Currently if I as an admin create a video node and upload the video, can see the video (and playback).

However if I am an anonymous user, I am unable to do any sort of playback even though I can access the video node. When I hit play in the JW player, I get a "Video not found or access denied" error even though I have made the video a public video. The path that I get along with the player is one that is incorrect as it has a "system" in it so my player is unable to play it.

What can i do to make sure that the uploaded files share the same permissions as the video node. So that if a user can see a video, they should be able to able to play it.

I went to admin -> file settings and changed the setting to Private so that Drupal controls the file system. Now an anonymous who does not have access to watch the video CANNOT see the player which is cool however they still cannot play the video on nodes they should have access to.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: I don't think that the `Download method` is the culprit here. In fact you shouldn't change in. That's rather an option you choose when you make the first install. How exactly do you embed the video in a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should provide more details about what modules you have enabled. If you do set a private download method (completely understandable), you may need to implement the file download hook.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_file_download/6